# yii2 hashing password register and signing in

Tags: php, hash, yii2, passwords

I cant successfully sign in using this script.

**Loginform.php**

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!$user || $user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect name/password.');
        }

    }
}
```

In my model I have this

**User.php**

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->password = $this->setPassword($this->password);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function validatePassword($password) {
    return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
}

public function setPassword($password) {
    return $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);

}
```

Here is my registration script

**Signupform.php**

```
public function signup() {
    if($this->validate()) {

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->save(); 
        return $user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please? thanks.

Comment: remove this from  signup function $user->setPassword($this->password);  

you already defins it in user model deforeSave Function

Comment: not working, theres nothing inserted in my table.. can you provide the customize scripts? thanks

Comment: it may some validation error print_r($user->.getError()) ; die();
can you please check this

Comment: @HasiburRahaman oi thanks brother!! you are right on the first place, im hashing the password twice.. what I did is I keep the $user->setPassword($this->password); in Signup function, and removed the $this->password = $this->setPassword($this->password); in the beforeSave(); and the last thing I changed which causing the problem is on my Loginform.

if (!$user || $user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect name/password.');
        }

after the OR i forgot to add ! .. thanks!!

Comment: You can check am post a answer  it may help you

Comment: sure brother..i will. thanks again.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Follow This :

**Model User.php**

```
public $c_password;  //Define a variable for confirm password

//This is rule

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['fname', 'lname', 'username', 'password',], 'required'],
        [['fname', 'lname', 'authKey', 'accessToken'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['authKey', 'accessToken'], 'safe'],
        [['username'], 'unique'],
        ['c_password', 'required'],
        ['c_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message' => "Passwords don't match"],

    ];
}


public function beforeSave($insert) {
            if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
                $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

iam create a function in site controller for registration you can create a model according to your need

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $model = new \app\models\Users;   
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('register', 'Registration Successful');
        return $this->redirect(['login']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('register', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

And This is my view file **register.php**

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'id' => 'login-form',
     'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
       'fieldConfig' => [
       'template' => "{input}\n{error}",
       'options' => [
        'tag' => false,
         ],
           ],
     ]);
?>           
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput([]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'c_password')->passwordInput([]) ?>
 <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```